# How to pass the value of a variable of a class to another class?

Tags: python

I have an infinite loop that updates the currentPrice variable in the streamingPrice class, I need to use the value of this variable Trading class, the refresh function in Trading class is going to keep retrieving the value of the currentPrice every time it updates, then I'm going to perform a task on it. The stream and refresh functions have their own threads. How can I achieve that?

Currently I only get the initialized value of that variable

```py
class streamingPrice(): 
  def __init__(self):
    self.currentPrice =0

  def stream(self):
    #Streaming live prices
    api = API(access_token=userVals.key)
    params = { "instruments": userVals.pair }
    r = pricing.PricingStream(accountID=userVals.accountID, params=params)
    rv = api.request(r)
    for ticks in rv:
        if('asks' in ticks): 
            self.setPrice(ticks['asks'][0]['price'])
  def setPrice(self,price):
    self.currentPrice = price

  def getPrice(self):
    return self.currentPrice


class Trading():
  def refresh(self):
      while(True):
       #initialize data channel
        self.highList, self.LowList, self.closeList = self.c.getData()
        self.tradeCurrentPrice = self.sp.getPrice()
        #Initialize Indicators
        self.rolling_bands_low = self.s.ROLLING_BANDS_LOW(self.closeList)
        self.rolling_bands_high = self.s.ROLLING_BANDS_HIGH(self.closeList)
        self.stochostic_oscillator_k = 
        self.s.STOCHASTIC_OSCILLATOR_K(self.highList, self.LowList, 
        self.closeList)
        self.stochostic_oscillator_d =  
        self.s.STOCHASTIC_OSCILLATOR_D(self.highList, self.LowList, 
        self.closeList)
```

Comment: Please see: [mcve].

Comment: You need to fix the grammar in the first paragraph. There seem to be two comma splices and maybe another typo or two that make it unreadable. As well, your code never calls either of the classes and it has a lot of undefined names, so you need to make a [mre]. You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

`self.tradeCurrentPrice = self.sp.getPrice()` is wrong because you have not defined self.sp.

Based on your title I assume you want to do something like this:

```py
sp = StreamingPrice()

trade = Trading(sp.currentPrice)
```

passing in the current price attribtue of the sp object into the new object.
Your Trading class will also need an `__init__(self, price)` method

there's also no need to create these methods:

```py
  def setPrice(self,price):
    self.currentPrice = price

  def getPrice(self):
    return self.currentPrice
```

because you can achieve the same result doing this:

```py
price = 3
sp = StreamingPrice()
sp.currentPrice = price
```